# How to measure QTcpSocket packet loss

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

Is there a way to retrieve packet loss or in this case retransmissions that have occured on a QTcpSocket? If there is a way, is there also a way to check the total amount of packets sent vs retransmissions?

Comment: I don't think Qt gets access to that, retransmission is handled at the kernel level